# How do make numbers format correctly in Kapacitor messages

Tags: kapacitor

Wrote a Kapacitor task that returns an alert message that I can then pipe to other outputs (Sensu, PagerDuty), the problem is that the formatting is not readable.

```
rabbitmq_memory_usage is CRITICAL: Memory used is too high on 
rabbit@prod-rb-fetcher37 at value: 3.949512928e+08!
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this can be done by passing it to `printf`

```
{{ index .Fields "mem_used_mean" | printf "%0.2f" }}
```